# What does $Az=y$ and $A^Tx=0$ imply about the relationship between $x$ and $y$?

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis

Suppose A is a $m \times n$ matrix and the vectors $x$ and $y$ are such that $Az=y$ for some vector $z$ and $A^T x=0$. Which one is correct?

1. $x^Ty=0$
2. $||x||_2=||y||_2$
3. $||x||_2 < ||y||_2$
4. $x=ay$ for some real values of $a$

Comment: I couldn't find a title for the question!

Comment: Write out $x^Ty$ using $Az=y$ and then remember that $(X^T)^T=X$ and $(XY)^T=Y^TX^T$

Comment: How about, for the title, "What does $Az=y$ and $A^Tx=0$ imply about the relationship between $x$ and $y$?"

Comment: @BillCook: $x^Ty=x^T(Az)=((Az)^T x)^T=(z^T A^T x)^T$, what should I do next?

Comment: Observe $(z^T A^Tx)^T=(z^T 0)^T=0$ :)

Comment: @DavidMitra: Maybe from now on I should use eyeglasses more often! Thank you. Could you please tell me what's the notation used in (2) and (3) called?

Comment: $L_2$ norm also called Euclidean Norm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's an answer...

(1) is the correct choice.

$x^Ty=x^TAz=x^T(A^T)^Tz=(A^Tx)^Tz=0z=0$

Comment: I'd like to know how (2), (3) and (4) are wrong, if it's possible for you. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: Take an Identity matrix as A and x becomes a zero vector. Y could be anything you want. Thus, option  2 gets kicked out.
Similarly, you can take an invertible matrix A with x,y,z all as zero vectors and still satisfy everything. Thus option 3 gets kicked out. Kicking out option 4 is a little taxing on my brain right now.

Comment: @Nunoxic: That's enough, thank you again.

Comment: All the rest of the parts can hold by picking the right choice of $A$, $z$, and $x$. They can also fail by picking the "wrong" choice. (1) is the only part which always holds.